# How To Change UITableView Cell Height Equally & Show detailedTextLabel?

Tags: uitableview, height, cell, detailtextlabel

Hi I have this code here.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://oo.mu/json2.php"];
    jsonData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL usedEncoding:nil error:nil];
    self.jsonArray = [jsonData JSONValue];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [jsonArray count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [indexPath row] * 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"];

    return cell;
}
```

What I want is:

1. To change the height of the `UITableView` cell so I can fit more
   things under the `textLabel`. (Currently, when I use the previous
   code to increase the height of the `UITableView` cell, each cell
   goes from big to small in different sizes).
2. To show under the `textLabel.text` a `detailedTextLabel` of
       something else under it.

How would I do that?

I tried:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[self.jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[self.jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Street"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[self.jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"City"];
```

But it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new UItableview cell with the dimensions as per your requirements. Later

```
-(Uitableview) cellForIndexPath {
    //add the customized Uitableviewcell.
}
```

In this way you can create the tableview cell as per your requirements. I hope it will help.